# Galaxy S4 changing UID / RFID after turning on

Tags: android, nfc, uniqueidentifier, rfid, hce

I'm trying to get the UID of my Galaxy S4 and i noticed that after turning on my S4 has a new UID.

Is there an option to set a static UID ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no API that permits you to set a static UID on the Galaxy S4.

However, depending on whether the Broadcom NFC controller supports this (there's no public information available about this) it might be possible to set a static anti-collision identifier when setting up the card emulation gate though NCI (NFC Controller Interface, see [NFC Forum](http://www.nfc-forum.org/) specifications). However, you would certainly need to create your own Android firmware with a modified libnfc-nci to do that.

**UPDATE:**
The Broadcom NFC controller does support setting arbitrary static UID values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360190/2425802) for further information.

Comment: Really exciting, the S4 doesnt work with Mifare Classic 1K Cards, they have another standard for NFC-Tags, but with the new S5 it works :o