# Get Static NFC Tag Id with HCE mode

Tags: android, nfc, uniqueidentifier, hce, serial-number

I'm new in NFC thing, so I tested several phones with calling getTagId() method in HCE mode, and this is the result:

```
device       | UID
LG G2        | random
LG G3        | static
S4           | random
HTC One Mini | static
Xiaomi mi3   | static
```

My questions:

1. Why do some phones have static UID and some do not? Is this chipset related?
2. Is it possible to get a fixed UID? I need it to authenticate the device.
3. On other side, I'm using Kitkat CyanogenMod 11 on Xperia M, but I did not manage to use it for HCE, why?

Any documents that can explain/support the answer?

Comment: What `getTagId()` method are you using? Could you describe your test setup?

Comment: Hi Roland, i was using getTagId in onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) on reader side

Answer (score 7):

**Why do some phones have static UID and some do not? Is this chipset related?**

That depends on the chipset and the implementation of the NFC stack. As far as I'm aware of, there are three different scenarios used by various Android NFC devices:

- The device has a secure element and uses the static UID of that secure element.
- The device generates a new random UID whenever it is turned on.
- The device generates a new random UID on every activation by an external reader device. I.e. whenever an external HF field is applied to the NFC antenna of the Android device.
- The device has no secure element but still uses a static UID (typically not *unique*), e.g. 0x01020304. *[Thanks to ErikM for pointing this out.]*

**Is it possible to get a fixed UID?**

Typically, you can't influence this. Specifically without modifying the Android device firmware (changes to the NFC stack) it's definitely not possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360190/2425802) for a method to set the UID value on Broadcom chipsets through modifying the libnfc-nci library.

**I need it to authenticate the device.**

Don't do this! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21705711/2425802) for more information on that.

Comment: Adding one more scenario here: The device has no secure element and uses a static UID, namely 01020304. Mainly used by Sony.

Comment: Well, it's not in my hand what design the given entity (office, college, etc.) uses for authentication. If they're using a system solely based on UID, all answers saying "don't do this" aren't helpful at all. I just want to know how to emulate, not how to design an authentication system.