# is it possible to get the ID that NFC of my android device is generating?

Tags: java, android, nfc

i want to get the ID of my android device.i use RFID to read that ID. but it shows something random each time.it means my hardware is generating a random code each time.

Comment: This question looks to me like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413567/how-can-i-read-the-nfc-id-of-another-android-device

Comment: actually no, I want to read that ID with RFID reader