# Can I change my phones' NFC UID info?

Tags: android, nfc, uniqueidentifier, serial-number

I need change my phones' **NFC UID** information. Because I'm developing a subproject for my university id card systems. The university works with `Student ID cards' UID` info.

Basically, I'm trying to use my phone as my student card.

I have a `raspberry pi` and `NFC reader circuit`, I can read my university cards' UID data but I can not fix my phones UID.

(when I put my phone on it, its NFC UID changes in every read.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Static NFC Tag Id with HCE mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239473/get-static-nfc-tag-id-with-hce-mode)

Comment: You might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/28409934/2425802