# emulate nfc card with selected UID on android

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, hce, secure-element

I want to ask 2question about nfc card emulate :

1. can I emulate nfc card include uid that I select?
2. I read [HCE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) and don't understand what is the diffrent between HCE and Card Emulation with a Secure Element?.

what are the disadvantage with the Secure Element ? i can't control on the card data/uid and on HCE I can?

Comment: what do you mean by "uid" ? AID (application Identifier) or UID of emulated tag ?

Comment: @LaurentY UID I mean the uid of the emulate tag ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Static NFC Tag Id with HCE mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239473/get-static-nfc-tag-id-with-hce-mode)

Comment: That not dup.  Lock on my 2 questions please

Comment: And not dup on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764476/host-based-card-emulation-with-fixed-card-id

Comment: I am also getting a random card ID, NfcEmulator.startNfcEmulator(cardAid, cardUid,[aesKey]) using Flutter. All I am looking for is to identify this device/user that has tapped. On the other side, I have a PN532 using the Adafruit library. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This subject may be a bit old but I was asking myself the same question.
Apparently the UID of the card emulated by your phone is random, but if you want to emulate the UID too you need to overwrite /etc/libnfc-nxp.conf, but it requires root privileges.
At least it works (or worked) for MIFARE Classic UID.

You can see more information on this link, slides 37 and + 
https://smartlockpicking.com/slides/Confidence_A_2018_Practical_Guide_To_Hacking_RFID_NFC.pdf

Comment: libnfc-nxp.conf does not seem to exist anymore but there is a file called libnfc-nci.conf. It probably doesn't have the option to change the UID anymore