# HCE - Is there a way to manipulate the ATR?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard, hce

I am making a Host Card Emulation app on Android, everything works fine with my PC/SC reader. I am able to send APDU commands and get the reponses. Now I want to know if it's possible to manipulate the ATR of the card emulated by Android using Android's NFC library (or not)? I have looked into the documentation but there's nothing about the ATR, does Android generate it automatically for each device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Android generates the answer-to-select (ATS) automatically. There is no Android API to change its contents. The same applies to the anti-collision identifier (UID).

#### ATS vs. ATR

Note that contactless smartcards (ISO/IEC 14443-4A) do not expose an ATR (answer-to-reset) during the activation sequence. Instead, they provide an ATS (in response to the selection procedure). PC/SC readers for contactless smartcards typically map parts of that ATS into an (emulated) ATR for compatibility.

#### Rooted devices

Even though Android does not provide an API, you might be able to modify values such as the ATS by modifying the NFC controller configuration files. See [Editing Functionality of Host Card Emulation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28409934/2425802) and [Host-based Card Emulation with Fixed Card ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19764476/2425802)